# Installing gdal 1.11 with virtualenv

Tags: python, centos, virtualenv, gdal

I have to install gdal 1.11 on my centos machine, and I got some problems with it.

I'm running on a virtualenv, using Python 2.7.5 instead of the Python 2.6 installed on my Centos

```
$ scl enable python27 bash
$ cd virtenv
$ source bin/activate
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

Since yum didn't provide the right version of gdal, I've been building it from source, downloading the tar.gz

This is I've done.

```
$ cd gdal-1.11.0
$ ./configure --with-python
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The last command shows me that it's building on the wrong version of Python, the 2.6 one.

What do I need to do to install it on the right version?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you tried to install it with pip?
You can pass the right version as argument.

pip install GDAL==1.11.0

Comment: According [to this doc page](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix) there is a `--with-pymodir` configure option. Perhaps you can use it to specify the `site-packages` directory in your virtualenv installation.

Comment: @danielfranca It is installing on the python 2.6 too, even if I'm using the pip version linked to Python 2.7.5

Comment: You might also want to run `./configure --help` to see if there are any other relevant options.

Comment: @unutbu I tried the --with-pymodir=/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ which is the directory for my python27, still installing in the python 2.6 dir

Comment: In fact it's processing GDAL-1.11.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg instead of the py2.7 one

Comment: Hm. The `sudo` in `sudo make install` is running `make install` as the root user -- in a root environment. So `make install` seems to be using `root`'s python, which is 2.6 not the virtualenv python2.7.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://tylerickson.blogspot.com/2011/09/installing-gdal-in-python-virtual.html)?

Comment: @unutbu yeah, still not working

Comment: Well, perhaps an easier way then would be to run `./configure --prefix=... --with-python` and set the prefix to somewhere you (as a non-root user) have write permission. Then run `make clean; make; make install`. (Not sure if `make clean` is valid; the goal is to make sure the new configure options take effect.) Note: omit the `sudo` when you run `make install`. This will hopefully give you an installation that at least you as the virtualenv user can use.

Comment: Please keep the terminal transcript -- it may give us clues if the above does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide has excellent instructions for installing GDAL on CentOS and Ubuntu.

http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html#gdal

It recommends building GDAL without python support and then building the python wrappers after. In your case I guess this would be:

```
$ cd gdal-1.11.0
$ ./configure --without-python
$ make install
```

and then for the python wrappers. From the directory containing the source folder:

```
$ cd gdal-1.11.0/swig
$ make
$ cd python
$ python setup.py install
```

Provided the virtualenv is active and your PYTHONPATH is set correctly when you call the python setup.py, it should build the correct version and install it to your virtualenv site-packages.